# CMake+SFML Linker error, even though library is specified in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I am making a project using SFML and CMake. To do that, I followed [the guide from SFML's GitHub](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake).
I am adding the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED network audio graphics window system)
if(SFML_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
else()
  message("SFML WAS NOT FOUND")
endif()
```

These lines are mostly just copied from the guide I mentioned. On ArchLinux, after installing SFML from the repositories, this works perfectly, and the generated MakeFile produces an executable

On Windows, after setting SFML_ROOT environment variable to my SFML location, CMake runs successfully, finding SFML and producing the following output:

```
Found SFML 2.4.2 in F:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/include
```

However, trying to build using the generated MakeFile results in a linker error:

```
...
C:\Users\complover116\Documents\CVMControl\src\cl_game.cc:14: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget7setViewERKNS_4ViewE'
C:\Users\complover116\Documents\CVMControl\src\cl_game.cc:15: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'
C:\Users\complover116\Documents\CVMControl\src\cl_game.cc:15: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'
... etc
```

Also, adding a debug command to CMakeLists.txt

```
message(${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

Outputs this:

```
debugF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-network-d.aoptimizedF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-network.adebugF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-audio-d.aoptimizedF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-audio.adebugF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.aoptimizedF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-graphics.adebugF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-window-d.aoptimizedF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-window.adebugF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-system-d.aoptimizedF:/Dev/CPPLibs/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-system.a
```

It is concatenated like this, I did not copy it incorrectly

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For output value of variable, contained a **list**, use *double quotes* around it: `message("${SFML_LIBRARIES}")`. Such a way list elements will be delimited with semicolon (`;`). As for errors arisen, they could be result of incompatibilities between the compiler used for the library, and the compiler used by your project. Make sure that you use the same compiler both for the library and the project uses it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The SFML page has direct links to the versions of the compilers used to build the official binaries, and I am using them specifically. But as for the list - thanks, I am new to CMake.

Comment: Which build tool you use on Windows (Visual Studio, MinGW, etc)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am using MinGW 6.1.0