# Link error with SFML library in CMake project on Windows

Tags: cmake, mingw, linker-errors, sfml

I'm trying to build a CMake project on Windows/MinGW and link it to SFML 2.5.1. CMake seems to find the libraries, and the program compiles fine, but I'm getting 'undefined reference' linker errors. I followed the [SFML 2.5 CMake build instructions](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0). What am I missing?

Errors:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable pressure.exe
CMakeFiles\pressure.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKSt6locale'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:/code/cpp/small/pressure/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My project's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(pressure)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

if(WIN32)
#set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(SFML_DIR C:/lib/cpp/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML)
endif()

set(SFML_LIBRARIES sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
set(pressure_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(pressure_VERSION_MINOR 1)
configure_file(
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
)
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "pressure")
find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio main network REQUIRED)
add_executable(pressure main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Can you please provide the verbose linker output so we can see what is being linked? You can try running `make VERBOSE=1` or similar.

Comment: Also, very similar error mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48661676/3987854) post. Perhaps, you can look at the responses there to see if they apply to your situation. Specifically, be sure you downloaded the correct MinGW version of SFML, not a Visual Studio version.

Comment: @squareskittles Indeed I was trying to use a Visual Studio version I had downloaded for another project! It links fine now with the MinGW 32-bit download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has been mentioned a few times on the Stack Overflow site:

- [SFML: undefined reference to _imp_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48661676/3987854)
- [Cannot compile SFML project using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45936971/3987854)
- [CMake+SFML Linker error, even though library is specified in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46895227/3987854)

More often than not, this *specific* linker error appears to occur when there are **incompatibilities** between the SFML libraries and what they are *linked to*. From the [SFML 2.5.1](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/) downloads page, there are several versions of the SFML pre-built libraries available. Make sure you download and reference the version that matches **your** compiler (e.g. MinGW, Visual C++ 12, Visual C++ 15, etc.).

On Windows, several different compilers are supported; so for example, if you are building your project with Visual Studio 15, be sure you've downloaded and referenced the Visual C++ 15 SFML libraries. Also be sure the SFML libraries match the *architecture* of your compiler (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit).

If you don't see the compiler you're using in the list offered on the SFML downloads page, you can download the SFML source and **build** it yourself using your compiler. This will help ensure the SFML libraries have binary compatibility with your project. Or, you can browse through [older versions](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/old-versions.php) of SFML pre-built libraries to see if any of those match the compiler you're using for your project.

Comment: you might also mention Visual Studio vs MinGW version on Windows, since those are for the same OS and thus adds more potential for confusion.

Comment: @voxoid Thanks, I updated the response to clarify that SFML supports many different Windows-based compilers.